# Minecraft Spigot create a New PlayerInventory

Tags: minecraft

So I want to create a new PlayerInventory, and am not sure if this is the way to go about it.

```
PlayerInventory inv = (PlayerInventory) Bukkit.createInventory(null, InventoryType.PLAYER);
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to ask you: "And what's your problem?"
If you exactly want to create player's inventory, then you're right. But I can't imagine why you want players inventory. If you mean to open inventory to player like a chest, then you can use another Bukkit method:

```
// Bukkit.createInventory(InventoryHolder owner, int size, String title);
// size = 9 * rows
Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, "Title");
player.openInventory(inv);
```

If you just want to get inventory and change it, then:

```
Inventory inv = player.getInventory();
```

Comment: I am asking as the way I showed doesn't seem right. I know about opening inventories and what not. I just would rather have an inventory to edit and move items around in because then with the inventory you can just easily replace it with the players current inventory. But I am doing it a different way just to make sure I don't get errors with it. Thanks though.